# Prevent Cookies From Being Sent on AJAX Request

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a web service that I invoke from script but that does not need any information stored in cookies. Anytime I make a request to the service, the cookie is sent along with it. I understand that by default cookies are sent with HTTP request, but is there any way at all to override that behavior and not send the cookie?

In a nutshell, I am issuing my request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) { successFunc(response); },
    error: function(xhr) { errorFunc(xhr); }
});
```

Answer (score 17):

Send AJAX requests to cookie-less subdomain on your server. So you app is www.mydomain.com and ajax requests are served from api.mydomain.com which you never set a cookie on. Also a great idea to do this with static files like images etc...

see the "Use Cookie-free Domains for Components" section of http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: Osseta, very good call on cookieless domains. We do this currently for other resources such as almost all of our static files. 

I need to elaborate a bit more on this web service. It is not stand-alone and contained in a subdirectory, so for the sake of this discussion say I am invoking methods in the same domain my web app is under but in sub-path "/publicservices/service.asmx."

Comment: I'm not certain, but I'm under the impression that cookie are a global config per (sub)domain. So they are either on or off and not configurable on a per request basis.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do believe you are right. Thank you very much for your insight!

Comment: Don't forget, this is probably only usable if you DON'T use the main domain - example.com (without www.). I personally don't like www, so I use the main domain, and this approach doesn't work for me since all the cookies for the main domain are included for all subdomains.

Answer (score 8):

Another approach would be prior to doing $.ajax:
1. get the cookies from the browser for your domain with javascript (save them in a global variable)
2. delete the cookies for your domain with javascript from the browser
3. do the $.ajax call
4. place the cookies (from the global variable) back in the browser.

If you don't need the cookies from your domain at all just delete them (so skip 1. and 4.).

Comment: Almost perfect... because there's no way to restore how much the cookie was going to live.

Comment: How make request without any cookie and without remove it.

Answer (score 4):

The withCredentials flag is needed to actually send cookies with cross-origin ajax calls.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Setting it to false will prevent cookies from being sent.

With same-origin requests you will need to follow the other answers mentioned here.

Comment: How do you reconcile that with this?    

_Setting withCredentials has no effect on same-site requests._  

While not obvious in my original question almost seven years ago, this .NET service was embedded in the website (_.asmx_ service in a folder nested in the site).

Comment: Fair enough. I'll make it clear that withCredentials=false prevents sending of cookies only on cross origin requests.

Comment: Note that if you're looking at this answer in the context of Chrome/Firefox extensions, I believe withCredentials is ignored there.

Answer (score 0):

No, the cookie will always be sent.

You could how your cookies are sent to the browser, and use the `http` flag on them, which means they won't be sent via javascript.

Or (which lots of sites use), create a new subdomain which you never sent any cookies on.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct in saying that browsers send matching (path + domain + session) cookies along with the HTTP request. This is critical for the cookie mechanism to work.

Couldn't you simply, not read the cookies?

Additionally, when the cookie is originally set, you can set what directory (and its subdirectories) can access the cookie.

For example, if you set a cookie to be read in /foo/bar/ only, a file located in /whatever/ajaxHandler.php cannot see those those cookies.

Check this out: http://us.php.net/setcookie

While I'm not sure if you're using PHP, it could be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Ignoring the cookie doesn't solve the problem of it consuming bandwidth

Comment: Foxtrot, I am curious what you mean by "simply not read the cookie". Also, to touch on your angle with setting them for specific directories, is is possible to set a cookie for the entire scope BUT a certain directory? If so, that would give me something to work with, I believe. Bear in mind this is all happening in the same domain and would need to be distinguished by a path in that domain. I don't know that cookies can handle that.

Is anyone aware whether jQuery itself allows for not sending cookie with an AJAX request? That would be the ultimate solution for me. =]

Comment: One does not always have the choice of not reading a cookie, for instance when authorization is handled via cookies on a framework before the view code is run.