# is it possible to ignore ajax cookies via javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

Is there a programmatic way in javascript to ignore cookies sent from the server (without changing browser settings).

We use certain plugins on our web server that will randomly update our security cookie. However this causes issues for some of our URLs and we want to ignore those cookies for some cases.

Our security architect recommended we look into this possibility.

example:
1). create ajax request with URL: www.site.com/abc/comtd
2). ignore any cookies that come back in the response

Comment: There is nothing in the Ajax request that says *ignore cookies*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Cookies From Being Sent on AJAX Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829201/prevent-cookies-from-being-sent-on-ajax-request)

Comment: its not a duplicate since that post is about not sending the cookies. This post is about ignoring the cookie in the set-cookie response header.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to send the AJAX request from a completely different domain. Because the AJAX would be a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) request, any response headers would be denied unless the server sends the `access-control-allow-origin` header. If the AJAX request is not a CORS request, the browser has to respect all `Set-cookie` headers it receives per [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send%28%29-method).

Answer (score 0):

its not an option in our case to change domains. We need to pass cookies to the server or the requests will not get through security. If we change domains our security cookies would not get passed. What we want is to pass the cookies but ignore any set-cookie response headers for  certain URLs.

I think this is not possible on the browser so I am investigating some Apache server plugins like mod_headers. Maybe we can do it on the server itself. Im closing this question and will open another one related to mod_headers.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - if you send the request from a WebWorker - I think that is isolated from the main browser context ?